# Object 'user' couldn't be found on 'Domain Controller'

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, domaincontroller

I have created PowerShell script to gather all users mailbox detail such as "PrimarySmtpAddress, Identity, displayname"  on Exchange On-Premises. I am trying to run this command from powershell:

```
$UserNameInSmtpFormat = Get-Mailbox -Identity $User -ErrorAction Stop | Select PrimarySmtpAddress, Identity, displayname
```

This command is working fine (`powershell.exe "c:\pstest\readUsers.ps1" 'Administrator@domain.com' 'Password' 'users.txt' 'http://Exchange/PowerShell/'`) Which is save as 'testok.cmd'

In this command I am getting error:- (`powershell.exe "c:\pstest\readUsers.ps1" 'User@domain.com' 'Password' 'users.txt' 'http://Exchange/PowerShell/'`) This is saved as 'testproblem.cmd'

I am getting the below error

**Error:-**
When I am giving the administrator account credential then it is working fine but when
I am trying to gather the same by using Normal 'User' Credential then i am getting below error;

> **The operation couldn't be performed because object 'user@domain.com' couldn't be found on 'dc.Domain.com'..Exception.Message**

Below is the Script

```
( #Constant Variables 
$Office365AdminUsername = $args[0]
$Office365AdminPassword = $args[1]
$UserNamesFile = $args[2]
$connectionUri = $args[3]   
#Main
Function Main {
#Remove all existing Powershell sessions
    Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
#Encrypt password for transmission to Office365
    $SecureOffice365Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Office365AdminPassword -Force
#Build credentials object
    $Office365Credentials  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Office365AdminUsername, $SecureOffice365Password 
Write-Host  "Credentials object created"
#Create remote Powershell session
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri -Credential $Office365credentials -Authentication Kerberos –AllowRedirection  
Write-Host  "Remote session established"
#Check for errors
if ($Session -eq $null){
    Write-Host  "Invalid creditials"
}else{
    Write-Host  "Login success"
    #Import the session
        Import-PSSession $Session
}
try {
    Write-Host  "SMTPADDRESS"

        Foreach($User in (get-content $UserNamesFile))
        { 
            Write-Host  "mailboxIdentity : $User"
            $UserNameInSmtpFormat =Get-Mailbox -Identity $User -ErrorAction Stop | Select PrimarySmtpAddress, Identity, displayname     

            $UserNameInSmtpFormat        
    }
    Write-Host  "ENDSMTPADDRESS"
} 
catch {
   write-host "EXCEPTION"
   write-host "`r`n $_.Exception.Message"
                                }
finally {
    Exit-PSSession
    Remove-PSSession $Session
                                }
}
# Start script
. Main  
)
```

Comment: Any chance you can post more of the script.  Based on what you have above; are you connecting remotely? Or do you have the Exchange Management Tools locally.  If you're connecting remotely I'd guess the users do not have the appropriate RBAC assignments and/or scopes.  Also; what are you specifically trying to accomplish?  What do you need the information for etc... This would help us provide alternative solutions etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was "Role Permission rights" and it is solved by giving the same to the user from which I was trying to get the mailbox detail. I have assigned the "Mail Recipient" role to the user from Permission tab in ECP.

Thank you.